# Ensuring two messages come from the same MPI task

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I am writing a MPI programming using python (mpi4py).  Many processes compute partial results, and send both the index and the update to the master task.  My code that gathers all the data is given as

```
if rank == 0:
    cb = dict((v,0) for v in graph)
    #print "initial is",cb
    while True: 
        neww = comm.recv(source=ANY_SOURCE, tag=1) 
        newdeltaw = comm.recv(source=ANY_SOURCE, tag=2)
        print "newdelw is",newdeltaw,"neww is",neww
        cb[neww]=cb[neww]+newdeltaw
        print "cb=",cb
```

But there is a race condition here which affects my results for large numbers of processors - I may have a situation in which `cb[neww]=cb[neww]+newdeltaw` in which data for `news` and `newdeltaw` comes from different process.  How do I prevent this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  For large inputs, *how* doesn't your program work well?  What makes you think you need to put a lock on something?

Comment: Whether I have a situation in which `cb[neww]=cb[neww]+newdeltaw` in which data for `neww` and `newdeltaw` comes from different process. The code for `send` resides in the main program, not in a `if conditional` like the given code

Comment: I still don't understand why a lock is needed.  Rank 0 will receive a neww from some processor, and then a newdeltaw from some (possibly other) processor, and update cb[neww] accordingly.  Nothing here needs locking.  What are you trying to accomplish, and what isn't working?  Please provide a simple piece of code which reproduces the problem you're having.

Comment: What happens when 'neww' is recieved from one process and `newdelta` is received from other process? Whether a case like that can happen?

Comment: Yes, it can happen.  If you don't want it to happen, pass a [status object](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/apiref/mpi4py.MPI.Status-class.html) to comm.recv, use `Get_source` to find out the source you just received from, and receive `newdeltaw` from that source instead of `ANY_SOURCE`.  Alternately, just pack neww and newdeltaw into one message.  Neither of those involve locking.

Comment: Tried the second suggestion. Worked perfectly. Saved my day. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While MPI has an in-order guarantee in the sense that two messages from rank 1 to rank 0 will be received by rank 0 in the order they will sent - one message cannot overtake the other - MPI says nothing, and can say nothing, about how they will be interleaved with other messages from other processors.  So you can easily get situations like:

```
  rank 1 messages to rank 0: [src 1, msg A, tag 1], [src 1, msg B, tag 2]  
  rank 2 messages to rank 0: [src 2, msg C, tag 1], [src 2, msg D, tag 2]

  rank 0 message queue: [src 1, msg A, tag 1], [src 2, msg C, tag 1], [src 2, msg D, tag 2], [src 1, msg B, tag 2]
```

So that rank 0 extracting a message with tag 1 will get rank 1's msg A, but then with tag 2 will get rank 2's msg D.  (Note that the message queue above satisfies the in-order guarantee above but doesn't help us here).

There's a few ways around this.  One is to filter the messages received for `newdeltaw` not just by tag but by source, to make sure it is from the same task that sent the `neww`:

```
if rank == 0:
    cb = numpy.zeros(size)
    rstat = MPI.Status()
    for i in range((size-1)*3):
        neww = comm.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, tag=1, status=rstat)
        src = rstat.Get_source()
        newdeltaw = comm.recv(source=src, tag=2)
        print "newdelw is",newdeltaw,"neww is",neww
        cb[neww]=cb[neww]+newdeltaw
        print "cb=",cb
else:
    data = rank
    for i in range(3):
        comm.send(rank,dest=0,tag=1)
        comm.send(data,dest=0,tag=2)
```

This way, only the tag-2 newdeltaw message from the matching source is received, avoiding the inconsistency.

Another approach is to avoid splitting the messages at all, by putting both pieces of data into the same message:

```
if rank == 0:
    cb = numpy.zeros(size)
    rstat = MPI.Status()
    for i in range((size-1)*3):
        (neww,newdeltaw) = comm.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, tag=1)
        print "newdelw is",newdeltaw,"neww is",neww
        cb[neww]=cb[neww]+newdeltaw
        print "cb=",cb

else:
    data = rank
    for i in range(3):
        comm.send((rank,data),dest=0,tag=1)
```

This bundles both pieces of data into one message, so they can't be separated.  (Note that once this is working, you can use more efficient lower-level mpi4py routines to avoid serializing the tuples:

```
if rank == 0:
    cb = numpy.zeros(size)
    rstat = MPI.Status()
    for i in range((size-1)*3):
        dataarr = numpy.zeros(2,dtype='i')
        comm.Recv([dataarr,MPI.INT],source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, tag=1)
        newdeltaw = dataarr[0]
        neww = dataarr[1]
        print "newdelw is",newdeltaw,"neww is",neww
        cb[neww]=cb[neww]+newdeltaw
        print "cb=",cb

else:
    data = rank
    for i in range(3):
        senddata = numpy.array([rank,data],dtype='i')
        comm.Send([senddata, MPI.INT],dest=0,tag=1)
```

Finally, you can avoid the master/slave approach entirely and have all processors working on their partial results in the problem, and then combine all the results at the end with a reduce operation:

```
cb = numpy.zeros(size,dtype='i')
totals = numpy.zeros(size,dtype='i')

data = rank
for i in range(3):
    cb[rank] = cb[rank] + data

comm.Reduce([cb,MPI.INT], [totals,MPI.INT], op=MPI.SUM, root=0)

if rank == 0:
    print "result is", totals
```